# Find element matching in 2 lists using java 8 stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

My case is:

```
class Person {
    String id ;
    String name;
    String age;
}
List<Person> list1 = {p1,p2, p3};
List<Person> list2 = {p4,p5, p6};
```

I want to know if there is person in `list1` that has the same name and age in `list2` but don't mind about `id`.

What is best and fast way?

Comment: in my case, equals can not be overrided

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Define yourself a key object that holds and compares the desired properties. In this simple case, you may use a small list whereas each index corresponds to one property. For more complex cases, you may use a `Map` (using property names as keys) or a dedicated class:

```
Function<Person,List<Object>> toKey=p -> Arrays.asList(p.getName(), p.getAge());
```

Having such a mapping function. you may use the simple solution:

```
list1.stream().map(toKey)
     .flatMap(key -> list2.stream().map(toKey).filter(key::equals))
     .forEach(key -> System.out.println("{name="+key.get(0)+", age="+key.get(1)+"}"));
```

which may lead to poor performance when you have rather large lists. When you have large lists (or can’t predict their sizes), you should use an intermediate `Set` to accelerate the lookup (changing the task’s time complexity from `O(n²)` to `O(n)`):

```
list2.stream().map(toKey)
     .filter(list1.stream().map(toKey).collect(Collectors.toSet())::contains)
     .forEach(key -> System.out.println("{name="+key.get(0)+", age="+key.get(1)+"}"));
```

In the examples above, each match gets printed. If you are only interested in whether such a match exists, you may use either:

```
boolean exists=list1.stream().map(toKey)
     .anyMatch(key -> list2.stream().map(toKey).anyMatch(key::equals));
```

or

```
boolean exists=list2.stream().map(toKey)
     .anyMatch(list1.stream().map(toKey).collect(Collectors.toSet())::contains);
```

Comment: I just wonder, is there any performance issues when create new set every time flatMap is call?

Comment: @thang do you mean the `filter` operation? When you use a method reference of the form `expression::name`, the `expression` will only be evaluated once, before a function using the result of the evaluation is created. Only the invocation of `name` will be repeated.

Answer (score 7):

A simple way to do that is to override `equals` and `hashCode`. Since I assume the equality between `Person` must also consider the `id` field, you can wrap this instance into a `PersonWrapper` which will implement the correct `equals` and `hashCode` (i.e. only check the `name` and `age` fields):

```
class PersonWrapper {

    private Person person;

    private PersonWrapper(Person person) {
        this.person = person;
    }

    public static PersonWrapper wrap(Person person) {
        return new PersonWrapper(person);
    }

    public Person unwrap() {
        return person;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null || getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        PersonWrapper other = (PersonWrapper) obj;
        return person.name.equals(other.person.name) && person.age.equals(other.person.age);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + person.name.hashCode();
        result = prime * result + person.age.hashCode();
        return result;
    }

}
```

With such a class, you can then have the following:

```
Set<PersonWrapper> set2 = list2.stream().map(PersonWrapper::wrap).collect(toSet());

boolean exists =
    list1.stream()
         .map(PersonWrapper::wrap)
         .filter(set2::contains)
         .findFirst()
         .isPresent();

System.out.println(exists);
```

This code converts the `list2` into a `Set` of wrapped persons. The goal of having a `Set` is to have a constant-time `contains` operation for better performance.

Then, the `list1` is filtered. Every element found in `set2` is kept and if there is an element left (that is to say, if `findFirst()` returns a non empty `Optional`), it means an element was found.

Comment: in my case, equals can not be override

Comment: @TodorNeykov That's what I guessed and I created a custom class with `equals` implemented, see my answer.

Answer (score 6):

Brute force, but pure java 8 solution will be this:

```
boolean present = list1
        .stream()
        .flatMap(x -> list2
            .stream()
            .filter(y -> x.getName().equals(y.getName()))
            .filter(y -> x.getAge().equals(y.getAge()))
            .limit(1))
        .findFirst()
        .isPresent();
```

Here, flatmap is used to join 2 lists. `limit` is used as we are interested in first match only, in which case, we do not need to traverse further.

Answer (score 3):

Well if you don't care about the `id` field, then you can use the `equals` method to solve this.

Here's the `Person` class code

```
public class Person {
  private String id ;
  private String name;
  private String age;

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

    Person sample = (Person) o;

    if (!name.equals(sample.name)) return false;
    return age.equals(sample.age);

  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    int result = name.hashCode();
    result = 31 * result + age.hashCode();
    return result;
  }
}
```

Now, you can use stream to get the intersection like so. `common` will contain all `Person` objects where `name` and `age` are the same.

```
List<Person> common = list1
      .stream()
      .filter(list2::contains)
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: in my case, equals can not be overrided

Answer (score 3):

```
<h3>Find List of Object passing String of Array Using java 8?</h3>
[Faiz Akram][1]
    <pre>
    public class Student {
        private String name;
        private Integer age;
        public Student(String name, Integer age) {
            super();
            this.name = name;
            this.age = age;
        }
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
        public Integer getAge() {
            return age;
        }
        public void setAge(Integer age) {
            this.age = age;
        }
    }
    </pre>
    // Main Class
    <pre>
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.stream.Collectors;
    public class JavaLamda {
        public static void main(String[] k)
        {
        List<Student> stud = new ArrayList<Student>();  
        stud.add(new Student("Faiz", 1));
        stud.add(new Student("Dubai", 2));
        stud.add(new Student("Akram", 5));
        stud.add(new Student("Rahul", 3));
        String[] name= {"Faiz", "Akram"};
        List<Student> present = Arrays.asList(name)
                .stream()
                .flatMap(x -> stud
                    .stream()
                    .filter(y -> x.equalsIgnoreCase(y.getName())))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(present);
        }
    }
    </pre>
    OutPut //[Student@404b9385, Student@6d311334]


  [1]: http://faizakram.com/blog/find-list-object-passing-string-array-using-java-8/
```

Answer (score 2):

This would work:

```
class PresentOrNot { boolean isPresent = false; };
final PresentOrNot isPresent = new PresentOrNot ();
l1.stream().forEach(p -> {
    isPresent.isPresent = isPresent.isPresent || l2.stream()
        .filter(p1 -> p.name.equals(p1.name) && p.age.equals(p1.age))
        .findFirst()
        .isPresent();
});
System.err.println(isPresent.isPresent);
```

Since `forEach()` takes Consumer, we have no way of returning and `PresentOrNot {}` is a workaround.

Aside : Where did you get such a requirement ? :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate over the two lists and compare the atributtes.

```
for(Person person1 : list1) {
    for(Person person2 : list2) {
        if(person1.getName().equals(person2.getName()) && 
                person1.getAge().equals(person2.getAge())) {
            //your code
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: need better java8 stream way :)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    OTSQuestions ots = new OTSQuestions();

    List<Attr> attrs = ots.getAttrs();
    List<String> ids = new ArrayList<>();
    ids.add("101");
    ids.add("104");
    ids.add("102");

    List<Attr> finalList = attrs.stream().filter(
            attr -> ids.contains(attr.getId()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

public class Attr {
    private String id;
    private String name;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

private List<Attr> getAttrs() {
    List<Attr> attrs = new ArrayList<>();
    Attr attr = new Attr();
    attr.setId("100");
    attr.setName("Yoga");
    attrs.add(attr);

    Attr attr1 = new Attr();
    attr1.setId("101");
    attr1.setName("Yoga1");
    attrs.add(attr1);

    Attr attr2 = new Attr();
    attr2.setId("102");
    attr2.setName("Yoga2");
    attrs.add(attr2);

    Attr attr3 = new Attr();
    attr3.setId("103");
    attr3.setName("Yoga3");
    attrs.add(attr3);

    Attr attr4 = new Attr();
    attr4.setId("104");
    attr4.setName("Yoga4");
    attrs.add(attr4);

    return attrs;
}
```