# Comparing a Input List with List of Repository Objects : Loop execution takes more time

Tags: java, hibernate, java-8, spring-data-jpa, java-stream

I get a List of Objects `List<APIObjects> apiObjectList` as an Input to my API (through HTTP-Post), I need to compare this Input-List with my List of Entity Object which i get by executing `repository.findAll()` with `Spring-boot-data-JPA` framework

Currently i loop the `List<DatabaseObject>` and then find if there is a match. Below is my code

```
public Boolean findIfAllAPIobjectsExist (List<APIObject> apiObjects) {
    List<DatabaseObject> databaseObjectsList = databaseRepository.findAll()

    return apiObjects.stream().allMatch {
        apiObject -> {
            for (DatabaseObject dbObject : databaseObjectsList) {
                if ((dbObject.getGroupId().trim().equals(dbObject.getGroupId().trim())) &&
                                (dbObject.getArtifactId().trim() .equals(dbObject.getArtifactId().trim())) &&
                                (dbObject.getVersion().trim().equals(dbObject.getVersion().trim()))) {
                            System.out.println("Matching ..");
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                    return false;
            }
        }

    }

}
```

But this looping seems to consume lot of time and Memory and How can it be tackled with Lambda functions ? I am pretty sure that my current methodology shown above (looping of DatabaseObject) isn't the right or professional way to tackle it

**APIObject.java**

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class APIObject{
    private String groupId;
    private String artifactId;
    private String version;
}
```

**DatabaseObject.java**

```
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "my_table")
public class DatabaseObject {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    String name;

    @Column(name = "group_id")
    String groupId;

    @Column(name = "artifact_id")
    String artifactId;

    @Column(name = "version")
    String version;
    }
```

Comment: Check this one - https://stackoverflow.com/a/34140736/2478531

Comment: Is there an `hibernate` or `spring-data-jpa` way of tackling this ? Probably with an `in` query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would override `equals` and `hashCode` in both of my Enties which hold the three attributes `groupId, artifactId, version` then sort the two List based on the three arrtibutes, and just use `.equals` to determine if the two Lists are equivalent or no :

```
databaseObjectsList.sort(
        Comparator.comparing(DatabaseObject::getGroupId)
                .thenComparing(DatabaseObject::getArtifactId)
                .thenComparing(DatabaseObject::getVersion)
);
apiObjects.sort(Comparator.comparing(APIObject::getGroupId)
        .thenComparing(APIObject::getArtifactId)
        .thenComparing(APIObject::getVersion)
);

return databaseObjectsList.equals(apiObjects);
```

---

With lombok you can use :

```
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = {"groupId", "artifactId", "version"})
class DatabaseObject {..}
```

Comment: Is there an `hibernate` or `spring-data-jpa` way of tackling this ? Probably with an `in` query

Comment: @Arun really I don't know, if there are a similar way in hibernate or spring-data-jpa, but you maybe you can find a solution, I'm here if you find it :)